# Properly escaping mysqli query in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Uggh, I've had a few beers and I just can't seem to progress.

I'm teaching myself a bit of PHP with MySQL (just because) and this one line just has me stumped:

```
$user = $mysqli->query ("SELECT id FROM members WHERE username = " . $_SESSION['user_name'] . " LIMIT 1");
```

I'm sure it's something completely stupid but I need to have the '$_SESSION['user_name']' passed with quotes around it.

Look, I know its a stupid question, apologies in advanced but I can't even get the right Google terms to find what I'm after... sad I know!\

I've tried all combinations of slash escaping and single / double quotes... please help!

Comment: You are missing the concatenate operator before your session variable. `$user = $mysqli->query ("SELECT id FROM members WHERE username = " .$_SESSION['user_name'] . " LIMIT 1");` and yeah **don't code** whilst you drink ;)

Comment: Add a concatenate operator (a dot) after username = " :

$user = $mysqli->query ("SELECT id FROM members WHERE username = " . $_SESSION['user_name'] . " LIMIT 1");

Comment: Uggh cant even ask for help properly... sorry guys, in code it is correct, I've adjusted the question.

Comment: I suggest you also  teach yourself what prepared queries are.

Comment: On it,  just testing at the moment, this is not 'user facing' code.

Comment: "user facing" shouldn't make a difference; get into good habits when working with all code, otherwise you'll forget one day that you are writing user-facing code; or somebody will decide to use your code as user-facing code

Comment: Truth blood... truth...  luckily I'm not to far in and I can rewrite the queries correctly. naoxink provided a good answer to this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use prepared statements :)

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id FROM members WHERE username = ? LIMIT 1");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $_SESSION['user_name']);
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the unescaped quotes, and concatenate operators. Try this:

```
$user = $mysqli->query ("SELECT id FROM members WHERE username = '" . $_SESSION['user_name'] . "' LIMIT 1");
```

Note the `'" . $_SESSION['user_name'] . "'` is changed.

Comment: Completely correct... oh man, thanks, I'll drink to you! Just another mind blank.

Answer (score 0):

```
$user = $mysqli->query ("SELECT id FROM members WHERE username = '" .  $_SESSION['user_name'] . "' LIMIT 1");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead

```
$user = $mysqli->query ("SELECT `id` FROM `embers` WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['user_name']."' LIMIT 0,1");
```

Answer (score 0):

As everybody stated before, the following would be a working (but not perfect!) query:

```
$user = $mysqli->query("SELECT `id` FROM `members` WHERE `username` = '" . $_SESSION['user_name'] . "' LIMIT 1");
```

**But please note:** Inserting strings in SQL queries this way is a security risk, since `$_SESSION['user_name']` may contain quotes itself, so that somebody attacking your site could execute *arbitrary SQL statements*! (Search for *SQL Injection* if you want to get more information on this.)

Using prepared statements as suggested by naoxink is a safer way, but I just want to mention another safe way to insert strings into SQL queries: Use the [`mysqli::real_escape_string()`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) method:

```
$user = $mysqli->query("SELECT `id` FROM `members` WHERE `username` = '" . $mysqli->real_escape_string($_SESSION['user_name']) . "' LIMIT 1");
```